# Flutter - How to give a color to an IconButton?

Tags: flutter, iconbutton

By reading documentation, i'm sure this is well-declared, but the add icon is still gray.

```
 class _TaskState extends State<Task> {    
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    



     return Scaffold(
           

appBar: AppBar(
             backgroundColor: Colors.red,
             title: Text('Tasks'),
             centerTitle: true,
             actions: <Widget>[
               IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                 color: Colors.white,
                 iconSize: 32.0,
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
               drawer: TheDrawer()
             );
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pay attention to linter warnings. You are not passing an `onPressed` parameter which is required for the `IconButton` constructor.

Adding it should solve your issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(Task());
}

class Task extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _TaskState createState() => _TaskState();
}
    
class _TaskState extends State {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text('Tasks'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            color: Colors.white,
            iconSize: 32.0,
            onPressed: () {
              
            }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the `onPressed` callback is `null`, the `IconButton` automatically greys itself out to indicate that the button is disabled. See [the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton/onPressed.html) for more information.